# Calculating time interval based on consecutive rows which are duplicates

Tags: r

**Goal**
I want to find out how long each user studies the overall time series combined.

**Problem**
Based on the data below, I do not know **how to get the total study duration of each user?** Especially because every time the location changes or that there is a large time gap, a new sequence starts.

**Some clarification**
The data for the timestamps and location are recorded through a person carrying a phone. Every once in a while, the phone records the time and the location of that person. Therefore, one could consider the data of one user to be a time sequence when the location does not change.

*Technically the timestamp in the real data set is a unix timestamp and the data set is very large:*

```
uid <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,1,3,2,2,2,1)
timestamp <- c(1,4,5,7,3,8,15,1,2,3,300,305,600,150,410,413,415,800)
location <- c("Library1","library1","library2","library2","library1","library2","library2",
              "library2","library2","library2","library4","library4","library4","library3",
              "library2","library1","library1","library1")
df <- cbind(uid,timestamp,location)

# Desired Output
uid.output <- c(1,2,3)
study.duration <- c(5,14,2)
df.output <- cbind(uid.output,study.duration)
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah, I added the desired output

Comment: How do you get 300, 200 and 150 ? Can you explain the calculation?

Comment: @RonakShah I only wanted to show how the output should look like... these are arbitrary values. I will calculate them by hand so maybe then this will make thinks clearer. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yes, please do as that will help. Do you need `aggregate(timestamp~uid, df, sum)` ?

Comment: Almost, but not quite. The problem is that the timestamps represent seconds. As such they can be seen as a running clock. And I need the time intervals. For example: User 1 is in library1 at time 1 until time 4. That would mean that the study duration of that sequence is (4-1 = 3). Later that person is in library 2 from time 5 to 7. Thus the total study duration is 3+2=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lri := rleid(location), uid][, 
    .(duration=sum(.SD[, timestamp[.N] - timestamp[1L], lri]$V1)), uid]
```

output:

```
   uid duration
1:   1        5
2:   2       14
3:   3        2
```